# Any way to edit a URI based on User Input?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, uri

I have an HTTP GET that is receiving information from a URI. The URI is for Google Shopping.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=key&country=US&q=digital+camera&alt=atom
```

(Left my key out).

Is there a way that I can change it from

```
q=digital+camera
```

to anything a user puts in an EditText?

So basically, I want the EditText to change what is searched on Google Shopping.

**First screen, ProductSearchEntry with EditText for search query:**

[image]

**Code for ProductSearchEntry**

```
public class ProductSearchEntry extends Activity{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.productsearchentry);

    Button search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);

    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent searchIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProductSearch.class);
                startActivity(searchIntent);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

**Then, I have a second class, ProductSearch, with no picture, but just this code:**

```
public class ProductSearch extends Activity{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.productsearchresults);
     EditText searchQuery = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchQuery);

        ProductSearchMethod test = new ProductSearchMethod();
        String entry;
        TextView httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.httpTextView);
        try {
            entry = test.getSearchData(searchQuery.getText().toString());
            httpStuff.setText(entry);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**Which references the ProductSearchMethod class which consists of a TextView that is changed to the code recieved in the HTTP GET:**

[image]

Code:

```
public class ProductSearchMethod {

public String getSearchData(String query) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URI site = new URI("https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=key&country=US&q="+query.replace(" ","+")+"&alt=atom");
     HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    request.setURI(site);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    String l = "";
    String nl = System.getProperty("line.seperator");
    while((l = in.readLine()) !=null){
        sb.append(l + nl);
    }
    in.close();
    data = sb.toString();
    return data;
    }finally{
        if (in != null){
            try{
                in.close();
                return data;
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

ProductSearchMethod comes up great, but it doesn't change the text from "Loading Items" to the website code. I had it working before but then I tried to edit what it searched (all this ^) and now it doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes in your code like

```
public class ProductSearchEntry extends Activity{ 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.productsearchentry); 
    EditText etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(id of your edittext);
    Button search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton); 

    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            //while calling intent 

            Intent searchIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProductSearch.class); 
            searchIntent.putExtra("searchText",etSearch.getText().toString());
            startActivity(searchIntent); 
        } 
    }); 
    } 
}
```

and another activity like this,

```
public class ProductSearch extends Activity{     
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){     
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.productsearchresults);     
        String searchQuery = getIntent().getStringExtra("searchText");     
        ProductSearchMethod test = new ProductSearchMethod();     
        String entry;     
        TextView httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.httpTextView);     
        try {     
            entry = test.getSearchData(searchQuery);     
            httpStuff.setText(entry);     
              } catch (Exception e) {     
                        e.printStackTrace();     
    }     
}     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... Change your getSearchData() method to include a string as a parameter

`public String getSearchData(String query) throws Exception{`

Then, insert that string into the query URL, replacing spaces with "+". You may want to do further conditioning to the string, for instance URL encoding it.

`URI site = new URI("https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=key&country=US&q="+query.replace(" ","+")+"&alt=atom");`

In your XML, create a button that contains the following line:

`android:onClick="search"`

In your ProductSearch activity, add the following method, and move the code in onCreate into it. You will also need to create an EditText in your XML for input.

```
public void search(View v)
{
    EditText searchQuery = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchQuery);

    ProductSearchMethod test = new ProductSearchMethod();
    String returned;
    try {
        returned = test.getSearchData(searchQuery.getText().toString());
        httpStuff.setText(returned);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Finally, you will probably want to read up on running asynchronous tasks so that the query won't freeze your app while performing.

Comment: Added bounty and changed OP up completely.

Answer (score 0):

May be I got you wrong, but why don't you just pass it as a parameter in

```
getSearchData() => getSearchData(string query)
```

Then you can change the line

```
URI site = new URI("https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=key&country=US&q=digital+camera&alt=atom");
```

to

```
URI site = new URI("https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/products?key=key&country=US&q=+ URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8")+&alt=atom");
```

Comment: What does the UTF-8 do? I mean how can I use this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://androidforums.com/developer-101/528924-arduino-android-internet-garage-door-works-but-could-use-input.html I use Asynctask to trigger a get command on a local Arduino server. It appends the Arduino's pin number and, depending on if it's needed, a port number to the end of the URL. I'm sure you could use it to help you out.